# Foreign Key Entity Framework 6.1 Code First create unecessary column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, data-annotations, foreign-key-relationship

I have this model

```
public class Event {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class EventAction {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int EventId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public Event Event { get; set; }

    public int? RelatedEventId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RelatedEventId")]
    public Event RelatedEvent { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate the code first migration, it tries to add a new `Event_Id` column instead of using my `RelatedEventId` even if I put the `ForeignKey` attribute to indicate the field to use.

This is not the first time I define multiple foreign key that link to same table, but I never went thru this problem before.

Here's the migration code generated

```
public override void Up() {

  AddColumn("dbo.EventActions", "Event_Id", c => c.Int());
  AddColumn("dbo.EventActions", "RelatedEventId", c => c.Int());
  CreateIndex("dbo.EventActions", "Event_Id");
  CreateIndex("dbo.EventActions", "RelatedEventId");
  AddForeignKey("dbo.EventActions", "Event_Id", "dbo.Events", "Id");
  AddForeignKey("dbo.EventActions", "RelatedEventId", "dbo.Events", "Id");

}
```

Comment: Is this the first migration or you are changing an existing schema?

Comment: @dotctor, I am changing an existing schema.  I add the new Column RelatedEventId on EventAction

Comment: Can you share the generated migration code?

Comment: @dotctor, I have added the migration code.  As you can see, it also add the foreign key I want, but I don't want the new "Event_Id" column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. 
For simplicity I have omited to include all my `Event` Class and also tought the problem was on `EventAction`.

So the missing piece in `Event` class is a collection to `EventAction`.

```
public class Event {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Title { get; set; }

  //this line was missing in my original post
  //and that's the one that was confusing entity framework
  public ICollection<EventAction> Actions { get; set; }

}
```

`EventAction` class contains two properties with `Event` type.
Entity framework must know which one we want to bind to.

So to accomplish this we need to, whith annotation, add `[InverseProperty("Event")]` on the collection property. Here, "Event" refer to property name, not the type.

Using Fluent API you have to use the overload version of `WithMany(d => d.Actions)` when defining the foreign key.